# Save svg without artboard in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have shape that I would like to save as svg file for web. I do:

```
Save as
Select Save as type SVG
Use Artboard is unchecked by default
Enter file name and save
```

Unfortunately I got huge art board and small shape on it in output `svg` file. How to omit artboard from picture?

Answer (score 5):

While I don't know of a way to do exactly what you're asking, a simple way to achieve the same result would be to make a new artboard for this one shape. There are two methods for this:

One is to select the artwork and go to **Object->Artboards->Fit to Selected Art**. This will resize the current artboard to the selected art.

If you don't want to change the current artboard, you can use the shortcut **Shift+o** to start editing the artboards, then single click on the shape you want. This will make a new artboard, sized to this shape. When you are done saving the art, you can hit **Shift+o** again, and remove the artboard you just created.

Answer (score 0):

You want to click that button labeled "Use Artboard" when you initially save the file. The button is at the bottom of the Save dialogue box. I'm pretty sure I figured this out accidentally because I was having the same issue as you're describing one time, but this time I checked off that box, just to see what it sis, and seems to be the fix! (; Oh, hey- Make sure you have sized the artboard as small as possible around the object itself beforehand. Otherwise when you check that box, the program will think you are asking it to use the whole (by default, anyway) big  artboard.